# Encryption in Hadoop

Tags: encryption, hadoop, cloudera

I'm new to Hadoop. I've read that several messages are exchanged between Name Node and Hadoop and that BlockReport messages are periodically sent by the Data Node to the Name Node. What I would like to know is whether these BlockReport messages are encrypted in Apache Hadoop(I don't mean any distributions of Hadoop like Cloudera) Is there any SSH encryption in the communication?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Hadoop by default has no encryption or authentication, although there are some options available.  The RPC messages can be encrypted with SASL, and authentication is possible with Kerberos. More recent versions also have the option to encrypt data transfers with SASL as well.  See the JIRA for more info: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-3637

Comment: So does it meant that by using a tool to analyze the messages exchanged between the different nodes, it would be possible to view all these messages in clear?I mean to ask if the BlockReport messages are transmitted as plaintext. Can you give me a format of BlockReport messages?